# Android Studio - I cannot see elements I made inside ScrollView, why?

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview

Well, I made ScrollView and inside it, I put one LinearLayout. Inside that LinearLayout, I put multiple LinearLayouts and it does not show any error. Also, as you can see image, you can see their shape and that they are constrained. But I cannot see source/background of the ImageViews and TextViews neither within Android Studio nor when I buil app, why?

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PQXn.jpg)

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1_1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stol"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stol"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/naslov" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/naslov"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
        android:text="POKER CHANCE CALCULATOR"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_cards"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/stol"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/stol"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/stol"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stol">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/table_card1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backside" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/table_card2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backside" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/table_card3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backside" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/table_card4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backside" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/table_card5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backside" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stol">

        <!--
        Početak vanjskog sloja!
    -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_vanjski_sloj"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scroll_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scroll_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scroll_view">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_first_row"
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stol">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_player1"
                    android:layout_width="159dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/okvir"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="338dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/player1_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="PLAYER 1"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_player1_2"
                        android:layout_width="144dp"
                        android:layout_height="103dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player2_card1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player2_card2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear2_stats"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/win_stats2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="WIN\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/draw_stats2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="TIE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lose_stats2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="LOSE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_player2"
                    android:layout_width="159dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/okvir"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="240dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/player2_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="PLAYER 2"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/player2_2"
                        android:layout_width="144dp"
                        android:layout_height="103dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player1_card1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player1_card2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear1_stats"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/win_stats1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="WIN\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/draw_stats1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="TIE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lose_stats1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="LOSE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_second_row"
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stol">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_player3"
                    android:layout_width="159dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/okvir"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="338dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/player3_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="PLAYER 3"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_player2_1"
                        android:layout_width="144dp"
                        android:layout_height="103dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player3_card1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player3_card2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear3_stats"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/win_stats3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="WIN\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/draw_stats3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="TIE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lose_stats3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="LOSE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_player4"
                    android:layout_width="159dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/okvir"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="240dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/player4_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="PLAYER 4"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/player4_2"
                        android:layout_width="144dp"
                        android:layout_height="103dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player4_card1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player4_card2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/backside" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear4_stats"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/win_stats4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="WIN\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/draw_stats4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="TIE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lose_stats4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="LOSE\n00,00%"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--
        Kraj vanjskog sloja!
        -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `NestedScrollView` instead of the `ScrollView` ...that usually this is only required for `CoordinatorLayout`, but it eventually may also be the case within a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Also, in the meantime, I have found out what is the problem with my code. There is an issue with LinearLayout inside ScrollView, its height and width cant be set to 0 and constrained to ScrollView. It must be wrap_content, match_parent, or fixed size.